# Iambic Pentameter

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, poetry

<sub>*Part of the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1)*</sub>

---

The type of party that may startle you

Defiant age range, kids no longer sweet

Irrat'nal number formed when over two

For adult and buffoon, it can succeed

A word my browser, Chrome, has near undo

Had worn a buckle that is for the street

A reddish laser must process to view

The place that you would find a thesmothete

It means brutal, harsh, or caustic too

In terms of verse like this, it's seven feet

8 5 7 3 6 10 3 6 6 10

----->

6 (=) 4

----->

2 8

----->

10 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Previous answers and comments have outlined all the answers to the clues already, plus one in chat. Please go and give the other answers some +1s for their work. I'll list the clued words here again, but without the extra space for all the lines:

> SURPRISE, TEENS, RADICAL, -ERY, SECURE, SEATBELTED, DVD, ATHENS, SAVAGE, HEPTAMETER

Now to interpret the numbers below the poem.

```
8 5 7 3 6 10 3 6 6 10
```

> Enumerations (word lengths) for the above answers, to help confirm when an answer was right. If the rest of the numbers are also enumerations, then these answers lead to a six-letter word and a four-letter word that we should equate.

```
6 (=) 4
```

> Taking the first letters of the ten clues words in order, we get STRESS (=) DASH. Somehow, the idea that stress=dash should lead to a two-letter word and an eight-letter word.

```
2 8
```

> Since this is a puzzle about poetic metre and syllables, Deusovi suggested in chat the idea of [scansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scansion#Common_2-_3-_and_4-level_notations), where stressed syllables in words are represented with lines (dashes, or rather macrons) and unstressed syllables are represented with a shorter rounder symbol.
>  This is a hint to reuse our ten clued words, but instead of looking at first letters, now look at stressed/unstressed syllable patterns. With stress=dash and unstress=dot, each word gives a letter in Morse code. (For example, [heptameter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heptameter) is ".-.."; in the provided link, the apostrophe indicates a stressed syllable.)
>  The Morse code letters spell out **AT DIAGONAL**.

```
10 4
```

> Finally, we need to use a diagonal somehow to extract a ten-letter word and a four-letter word. In this case, we're not using the clued words again; we're going back to the original clues.
>  Ten lines of ten syllables each; taking the diagonal in this case means taking the first syllable of the first line, then the second syllable of the second line, and so on.
>  **THE**, **-FI-**, **'NAL**, **AND**, **-SER**
>  **THAT**, **PROs-**, **THE[s]-**, **-TIC**, **FEET**
>  (I think the sixth line may be off by a syllable and should be **IS**.)

Final answer for this poetic puzzle:

> The final answer is **PROSTHETIC FEET**.

Answer (score 5):

The type of party that may startle you

> SURPRISE

Defiant age range, kids no longer sweet

> TEENS

Irrat'nal number formed when over two

> ROOTTWO? (Not sure about this)

For adult and buffoon, it can succeed

> ERY. (Adultery and Buffoonery. Succeed meaning like Suffix)

A word my browser, Chrome, has near undo

> SECURE? (Riley)

Had worn a buckle that is for the street

> SEATBELTED (Deusovi)

A reddish laser must process to view

> ROM or UPC

The place that you would find a thesmothete

> ATHENS

It means brutal, harsh, or caustic too

> SAVAGE (Riley)

In terms of verse like this, it's seven feet

> HEPTAMETER

If these are correct, then,

> The first letters spell out STRESS RASH. The equal sign suggests we look for a word (s) that means Stress and Rash.

Comment: Hm, I had "SEATBELTED" and "UPC" for number 6 and 7. But I think the rest are right (and nice find with "ery"!)

Comment: Ah ha! SEATBELTED makes more sense than my answer. Good one.

Comment: #3 could be RADICAL and #5 could be SECURE. If #9 is SAVAGE then the first letters spell STRESS RASH, but I don't know what that means.

Comment: I thought of E as a possible different interpretation of #3, and #4 might be EDIT or REDO (at least on Mac – I don't know about other platforms).

Comment: The browser word is SELECT, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer:

The type of party that may startle you

> Jeopardy?

Defiant age range, kids no longer sweet

> Puberty or Teenage

Irrat'nal number formed when over two

> Root of two?

For adult and buffoon, it can succeed

A word my browser, Chrome, has near undo

> Redo?

Had worn a buckle that is for the street

> Street Belt

A reddish laser must process to view

> Compact Disk

The place that you would find a thesmothete

> Athens

It means brutal, harsh, or caustic too

In terms of verse like this, it's seven feet

> Not pentameter then? Heptameter? (Pentameter is 5 feet)

8 5 7 3 6 10 3 6 6 10

----->

6 (=) 4

----->

2 8

----->

10 4

Cant figure out what the numbers could mean.

Comment: I am guessing the numbers are enumeration for the clues.